# Linked List not updating values

Tags: java, android, object, linked-list

So I've debugged my program and have found that the part of my program is updating, whilst another isn't.

I have a method:

```
public void storeApplication(String name, String item){
     Application app = new Application(name, item);
     peopleAttending.add(app);
}
```

The debugger reports that an object is contained in the LinkedList (peopleAttending).

In another method:

```
public void populateListView() {

    int noOfPeopleAttending = peopleAttending.size();
    String noPeopleAttending = String.valueOf(noOfPeopleAttending);

 Toast.makeText(GuestsAttending.this, noPeopleAttending, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

This method can be called after the previous one and states that there isn't an object within the LinkedList.

I've checked the object references just to make sure that they are pointing at the same reference and they are.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Entire Class:

```
public class GuestsAttending extends Activity {

private LinkedList<Application> peopleAttending = new LinkedList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_guests_attending);

    populateListView();


}

public void storeApplication(String name, String item){
     Application app = new Application(name, item);
     peopleAttending.add(app);
}

public void populateListView() {
   // GuestsAdapter adapter = new GuestsAdapter(this, peopleAttending);
   // ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
   // listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    peopleAttending.size();
    int noOfPeopleAttending = peopleAttending.size();
    String noPeopleAttending = String.valueOf(noOfPeopleAttending);

 Toast.makeText(GuestsAttending.this, noPeopleAttending, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Second Edit:

Java Booking Screen Method:

```
  public void saveBookingInfo(View view) {

    GuestsAttending sendApplication = new GuestsAttending();

    EditText applicantNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.applicantNameTextField);
    EditText itemToBurnText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemToBurnTextField);

    String appName = applicantNameText.getText().toString();
    String appItemToBurn = itemToBurnText.getText().toString();

    if (appItemToBurn.isEmpty() || appName.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(BookingScreen.this, "Please fill in all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {


       sendApplication.storeApplication(appName, appItemToBurn);
    }
}
```

GuestsAttending Java Class: -- See Above.

Comment: Since you have a debugger, can you attach a breakpoint to stop the execution every time peopleAttending is accessed, and hence find if some other operation is emptying the list? You are 100% sure peopleAttending is the same object in both cases?

Comment: 100% -- I've been breakpointing for most of the day, and so far no luck. :/

Comment: What about a `peopleAttending.clear()` somewhere between the 2 pieces of code?

Comment: @Matthew Levene You need to share more code. We dont know the program flow, the bug might be in the code you have not shared. For example we dont know whats the scope of peopleAttending variable.

Comment: @AbbéRésina No code like that in my program. See my edit.

Comment: @vinay Added the class at the bottom of my post

Comment: 'This method can be called after the previous one' - can be, or is called? Are you sure this to be the case?

Comment: @copeg 'populateListView' can be called before 'storeApplication', but it will always return 0 (As the storeApplication method is responsible for adding the objects).

Comment: Well, if storeApplication is the only location in which objects are added and it has not been called, the list will be empty. Perhaps you should define a more workable example that demonstrates the workflow and the problem...eg that storeApplication has been called before populateListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Useful hint**: It's really popular to set type of List as a `List<>` interface from `java.util` package instead of `LinkedList<>` itself.

Anyway, i am pretty sure that `storeApplication` method is not automatically triggered before onCreate method ran by Activity framework. Maybe your debugger is stopoing on it in different order (because of using threads or smth), but you should to log some invoke. Try to find it out.

Comment: storeApplication() is triggered by another class (which is linked to the XML that I get the data to store from)

Comment: Can you share somehow how you configured this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what the problem is:

When I submit the booking information, it runs all the necessary methods. However, when the "storeApplication()" method has finished executing, the ArrayList 'empties' all the objects out.

I only noticed this when I used breakpoint and tried running the method twice, on the second time I entered booking details, the ArrayList stated it was empty.

I'm going to see if I can try and store the ArrayList in a more secure place.